# how to install Gitlab on Amazon Linux 2023 (x86)?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I automate gitlab installation on the AWS Ubuntu image but i need to swicth to Amazon Linux 2023 (x86) image.

I looked on the net, it is not clear if Gitlab may be installed on Amazon Linux 2023 (x86).

The first point is packages repositories, on ubuntu the reposotiries configuration has to be updated with the command "curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | bash"

Is there an similar command for Amazon Linux 2023 (x86) ?